# Implementing an accordion in AngularJS and better understanding $scope

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am editing an already existing Angular webpage. In the app.js file, there are multiple controllers for each page. Here's their template:

JS:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.useSettings({
Header: "header",
Title: "title",
mainImg: "main.png",
fields: [{
  fieldText: "text",
},{
  fieldImg: "pic.jpg",
},{
  fieldAccordion:
 // 
},{
]
});
});
```

My goal is to have fieldAccordion work as an accordion for the data that I input there, just how all my fields work.

This is my Unordered List data type in the html file:

```
<div class="basic-page__field__undordered" ng-
if="field.fieldUnorderedList">
<ul class="field-list field-list--unordered">
<li ng-repeat="listItem in field.fieldUnorderedList">{{ listItem }}
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I can simply use it in the .JS file like this:
    fieldUnorderedList: [
    "item1",
    "item2",
    ]

So I would like to find a similar way to use data for an accordion type.

Here is how I wrote it in the .html file:

```
<div class="basic-page__field__accordion" ng-if="field.fieldAccordion">
<ul class="field-list field-list--accordion">
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="accordion.current = item.name">
{{item.name}}
<ul ng-show="accordion.current == item.name">
<li ng-repeat="sub in item.sub">{{sub.name}}</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now the issue that I'm having is getting it to work as simple as using
    "fieldAccordion:" in my controller.

I have done some research and what I don't understand is this:
All my controllers have the same template with $scope.useSettings, followed by all the data such as fieldText, fieldImg, etc.

How would I add another $scope that deals with the accordion data type which I can use in the exact place that I want it to be?

Something like this:

```
$scope.accordion = {
current: null
};

$scope.items = [{
name: 'List 1',
sub: [{
name: 'Sub 1.1'
},{
name: 'Sub 1.2'
}]
},{
name: 'List 2',
sub: [{
name: 'Sub 2.1'
}]
},{
name: 'List 3',
sub: [{
name: 'Sub 3.1'
},{
name: 'Sub 3.2'
},{
name: 'Sub 3.3'
}]
}];
}]);
```

This is one of my biggest obstacles in getting to understand AngularJS. Since I am working on an already existing webpage, I don't know how to add multiple $scopes for one controllers and where to use them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. A controller should only have one scope. Why do you feel you need more than one.

Comment: also in your template i see field.fieldAccordion but i dont see field in your controller. Is this using controllerAs?

Comment: Well that is my question: How do I use fieldAccordion in my controller ?

Comment: that wasn’t my question though.... please read on the angular documentation how the scope of a controller works. Should make this easier. every property of the scope of a controller “foo” should be bindable in the html within  ng-controller=“foo”